# Manipulate RMarkdown metadata from within R code chunks

Tags: r, metadata, knitr, r-markdown

In short: Is there a way to manipulate RMarkdown's `metadata`-list generated from the YAML header from within the following R-code chunks? To illustrate, I've tried the following:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
rmarkdown::metadata$title <- "New title"
rmarkdown::metadata$title
```
````

This throws an error, though.

```
Error in rmarkdown::metadata$title <- "New title" : 
  Object 'rmarkdown' not found
```

### Background

I'm working on a RMarkdown TeX-template. Some parts of the preamble need to be localized depending on the variable `lang` defined in the YAML header. My current approach is to check the value of `metadata$lang` and create a list of corresponding terms. I wanted to add the contents of the list to `metadata` and access the terms in the TeX-template via `$loc_wordcount$`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer to this is no (though, I'm not 100% sure of that).

But, there is a different way to do it.  You can use a parameterized report (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html).

The way to do that would be:

Create an rmarkdown file (e.g. called "`input.Rmd`") with parameters named `param$value`:

```r
---
title: "params$new_title"
output: html_document
---

The rest of the report goes here.
```

Then render the report with a parameter passed in:

```r
rmarkdown::render('input.Rmd', params = list(new_title = "New title"))
```