# Add r chunk within output of html_document - css files

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

I would like to add css files into my Rmd using `r chunk`. For example

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
    html_document:
        css: '`r system.file("shinydashboard.css" , package = "shinydashboard")`'
---
```

but I got error:

```
pandoc: Could not fetch `r system.file(
`r system.file(: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
Execution halted
```

I read both related questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449319/yaml-current-date-in-rmarkdown) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637340/inline-r-code-in-yaml-for-rmarkdown-doesnt-run?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but they did not cover situation when `r chunk` occurs in `html_document` output (Ramnathv mentioned `brew` package but I did not test it, besides it was posted in '14.).

It would be great if it would be possible to do it, and still using `Knit` button in RStudio.

Thanks,

**Update**

Another thing is when I want to include all .css files from one directory using `r chunk` within `html_document`. Here I want to include all files from `www` directory:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
    html_document:
        css: "`r x <- list.files(path = 'www', pattern = '*.css', full.names = T); x <- paste(x, collapse = '\', \'');z <- paste0('[ \'', paste0(x, collapse = ', '), '\' ]'); z`"
---
```

Comment: Using `htmltools::includeCSS(system.file("shinydashboard.css" , package = "shinydashboard"))` in the 'setup' R chunk doesn't work?

Comment: It does not work. Besides what if you have a html file which you want to add in `before_body`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression in the *YAML* header must be formatted using `!expr` (*see note at the bottom*).

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document:
    css: !expr system.file("shinydashboard.css" , package = "shinydashboard")
---


## Header

```{r meta}
rmarkdown::metadata
```
````

This produces the following output where you can clearly see the *CSS* loaded correctly.

[image]

To understand what is happening during the render, it is valuable to look at the `pandoc` command being run. For your multi-file update, we can run *static* and *dynamic* for a comparison.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document:
    css: [ 'www/file1.css', 'www/file2.css' ]
---

# /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS so.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output so.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template /usr/share/R/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --css www/file1.css --css www/file2.css --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header /tmp/RtmpRdKgYW/rmarkdown-str3eef4edabf99.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
```

Importantly, you will see `--css www/file1.css --css www/file2.css`, and the file renders correctly with both *CSS* files included.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document:
    css: !expr x <- list.files(path = "www", pattern = "*.css", full.names = T); x <- paste(x, collapse = "\', \'"); z <- paste0("[ \'", paste0(x, collapse = ", "), "\' ]"); z
---

# /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS so.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output so.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template /usr/share/R/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --css "[ 'www/file1.css', 'www/file2.css' ]" --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header /tmp/RtmpMStG00/rmarkdown-str423c7a02dab7.html --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
```

Where we unfortunately find `--css "[ 'www/file1.css', 'www/file2.css' ]"`. I have tried a few tricks including: `cat`, `capture.output`, `as.name`, and `noquote` without luck. An enhancement may be required to `rmarkdown` to present this in the required form to `pandoc`.

> **N.B.** It is worth noting this is indeed a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637340/inline-r-code-in-yaml-for-rmarkdown-doesnt-run) question where the answer by [Eli Holmes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2403645/eli-holmes) demonstrates the alternate syntax. He also notes a change in the development version, which may include the `css` field.