# Quotes and inline R code in Rmarkdown YAML

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to add some special fonts as part of the title/subtitle in an R markdown document but I'm getting different results depending on the quote types I'm using.

Here's a small R markdown example that shows my problem. I would like to print the twitter logo before the twitter handle as part of the R markdown subtitle.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
subtitle: '`r fontawesome::fa("twitter", fill = "steelblue")` @twitter handle'
author: "My Name"
date: "7/12/2018"
output: html_document
---

This is it.
```

If I use single quotes then I almost get the result I want. There is a newline between the logo and the twitter handle as shown below but that is fine - it could be fixed with css since the logo is set inside `<svg> ... </svg>`.

However, if I use double quotes then things go haywire:

```
subtitle: "`r fontawesome::fa('twitter', fill = 'steelblue')` @twitter handle"
```

Now *none* of the YAML information turns up in the final html document. I'm guessing that it is related to [this question on entering the current date as part of the yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449319/yaml-current-date-in-rmarkdown) or possibly [this post where the YAML inline code doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637340/inline-r-code-in-yaml-for-rmarkdown-doesnt-run) but I am curious as to *why* the change of quote types in the YAML has such a profound impact on the rendering since the double quotes clearly work for the other YAML parameters.

I'm using `rmarkdown` v1.10.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fontawesome::fa()` function returns a `SVG` element.
For instance, the string returned by `fontawesome::fa("twitter", fill = "steelblue")` is:

```
<svg style="height:0.8em;top:.04em;position:relative;fill:steelblue;" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
  <path d="M459.37 151.716c.325 4.548.325 9.097.325 13.645 0 138.72-105.583 298.558-298.558 298.558-59.452 0-114.68-17.219-161.137-47.106 8.447.974 16.568 1.299 25.34 1.299 49.055 0 94.213-16.568 130.274-44.832-46.132-.975-84.792-31.188-98.112-72.772 6.498.974 12.995 1.624 19.818 1.624 9.421 0 18.843-1.3 27.614-3.573-48.081-9.747-84.143-51.98-84.143-102.985v-1.299c13.969 7.797 30.214 12.67 47.431 13.319-28.264-18.843-46.781-51.005-46.781-87.391 0-19.492 5.197-37.36 14.294-52.954 51.655 63.675 129.3 105.258 216.365 109.807-1.624-7.797-2.599-15.918-2.599-24.04 0-57.828 46.782-104.934 104.934-104.934 30.213 0 57.502 12.67 76.67 33.137 23.715-4.548 46.456-13.32 66.599-25.34-7.798 24.366-24.366 44.833-46.132 57.827 21.117-2.273 41.584-8.122 60.426-16.243-14.292 20.791-32.161 39.308-52.628 54.253z"/>
</svg>
```

**This string contains double quotes**: this is the reason why single quoting leads to a proper result and double quoting does not perform well.
It is clear if you inspect the intermediate `markdown` file using the `keep_md` option:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
subtitle: "`r fontawesome::fa('twitter', fill = 'steelblue')` @twitter handle"
author: "My Name"
date: "7/12/2018"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---
```

These quoting considerations can be done away using YAML [literal](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688) or [folded](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2796251) blocks:

```
subtitle: |
    `r fontawesome::fa('twitter', fill = 'steelblue')` @twitter handle
```

or

```
subtitle: >
    `r fontawesome::fa('twitter', fill = 'steelblue')` @twitter handle
```

Comment: Wondeful explanation. Just what I was looking for