# R flexdashboard, title is truncated when using a variable

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am using this pseudo code to generate dynamic title on an flexdashboard in R

```
title_Var <- paste("Numurkah", format(max(Data$`Cutt Off daily`), "%d %b %Y"))
```

which works fine in the R console : Numurkah 09 Oct 2018

but when I use it inside the RMD file, (this code is inserted after I defined my variable in r)

```
---
title:  \`r title_Var`\

---
```

it render in the HTML file as
 09 Oct 2018
so YAML get my variable correctly, but it show only the date not the first text " Numurkah"

thanks for the reply, I found the correct answer

```
---
title:  `r title_Var`
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some restrictions on which YAML lines R code can execute from (see for example [Inline R code in YAML for rmarkdown doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637340/inline-r-code-in-yaml-for-rmarkdown-doesnt-run)). You can create the title with system parameters, it seems, but not with variables that are identified later in the markdown doc. For example this works:

```
---
title: '`r paste("Numurkah", format(Sys.Date(), "%d %b %Y"))`'
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B %Y")`'
output: html_document
---
```

Comment: thank you very much, the correct code is :   title:  `r title_Var`